# Why am I getting an error in failed with error code?

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip

I am trying to install a package with pip, but I am getting this error. How can I fix this? I have already tried reinstalling pip and other python packages and updating it.

```
Collecting icount
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/1b/785202907a94d2c2968727a48bac503f03e236f5b11bcc31bc2a0c3ab826/iCount-2.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in iCount setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Unordered types are not allowed
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Uq6EGX/icount/
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 1):

> pip version 10.0.1

This is VERY OLD version. Upgrade:

```
pip install --compile --upgrade "pip<21.0" "setuptools<45"
```